# Recover python in /usr/bin

Tags: software-installation, python, libraries, executable

I tried to install a newer version of the python and associate with the /usr/bin folder. Hence, in the configure file of that newer version I modified initialization location from /usr/local to /usr. 
When I tried to install python in that manner, the compilation failed during the "sudo make install command" . Now the python executable /usr/bin/python has some issues. When I use python executable it says "ImportError: No module named time". Is there a way to recover the python library?

Comment: That's a bad idea. You should have stuck to `/usr/local`.

Comment: @edwinksl Is it possible to recover the python library and the executable

Answer (score 0):

After being stuck with this problem myself for hours, the only thing that did the trick was

`apt --reinstall install libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal`